# How to create a Linux compatible zip archive of a directory on a Mac

Tags: linux, macos, zip, gzip

I've tried multiple ways of creating a zip or a tar.gz on the mac using GUI or command lines, and I have tried decompressing on the Linux side and gotten various errors, from things like "File.XML" and "File.xml" both appearing in a directory, to all sorts of others about something being truncated, etc.

Without listing all my experiments on the command line on the Mac and Linux (using tcsh), what should 2 bullet proof commands be to:

1) make a zip file of a directory (with no __MACOSX folders)

2) unzip / untar (whatever) the Mac zip on Linux with no errors (and no __MACOSX folders)

IT staff on the Linux side said they "usually use .gz and use gzip and gunzip commands".

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much research and experimentation, I found this works every time:

1) Create a zipped tar file with this command on the Mac in Terminal:

`tar -cvzf your_archive_name.tar.gz your_folder_name/`

2) When you FTP the file from one server to another, make sure you do so with binary mode turned on

3) Unzip and untar in two steps in your shell on the Linux box (in this case, tcsh):

`gunzip your_archive_name.tar.gz`

`tar -xvf your_archive_name.tar`

Comment: Just do `tar xvfz ...` to extract.  The `z` has `tar` call `gzip` for you, and you avoid creating a large, intermediate `.tar` file.

Comment: That will not prevent resource fork/extended attribute information from being put in the tar file, which shows up as `._*` files.  Nor will it prevent `.DS_Store` files from being archived.  See my answer for how to avoid those.

Comment: It's also **not** a "zipped" file, at least by the traditional definition of "zipped." A `.zip` file is compressed with PKZIP or any of the utilities based on the Info-Zip package, including `zip`/`unzip` and WinZIP. `gzip` uses the same compression scheme, but it does **not** archive. Its use case is to serve as a filter for `tar`. The more recent additional "zips," including `bzip2` (another compressor-only) and `7Zip` (archive+compress), only serve to confuse things.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac and in ssh bash I use the following simple commands:

```
Create Zip File (-czf)
tar -czf NAME.tgz FOLDER
Extract Zip File (-xzf)
tar -xzf NAME.tgz
```

Best, Mike

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `File.XML` and `File.xml` cannot both appear in an HFS+ file system.  It is possible, but very unusual, for someone to format a case-sensitive HFSX file system that would permit that.  Can you really create two such files and see them listed separately?

You can use the `-X` option with `zip` to prevent resource forks and extended attributes from being saved.  You can also throw in a `-x .DS_Store` to get rid of those files as well.

For `tar`, precede it with `COPYFILE_DISABLE=true` or `setenv COPYFILE_DISABLE true`, depending on your shell.  You can also throw in an `--exclude=.DS_Store`.

Your "IT Staff" gave you a pretty useless answer, since gzip can only compress one file.  gzip has to be used in combination with tar to archive a directory.

Comment: On my mac, I had gotten mixed case XML and xml files. For the script, I normalized them by simply renaming them all to lower case. In one of the zip attempts, I forget which one, the archive unzipped on the Linux box with both in there! 

I do have a working solution after much trial and error. I'll post it below.

Comment: Linux _does_ allow file names that differ only in case.  To get that you would have archive two files in different directories on the Mac whose names differ only in case (since they can't coexist in the same directory), and the unarchive them into the same directory on Linux.

Comment: Mark, my current statement is "tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz my_folder/". How do I integrate the -x option? I tried and it said I can't have both c and x.

Comment: You need to read the answer more carefully.  `-x` is for `zip`.  For `tar` you use `--exclude`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!